# Перехват Http запроса в браузерах.

Tags: http, .net, delphi-7

Перехват Http запроса в браузерах.
Как в Google Chrome перехватить переход на сайты или страницы. В Delphi или же на C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. можно использовать tcpdump или wireshark
2. иногда просто достаточно хваитает плагина в браузере, типа http 
   header + firebug

Answer (score 4):

InjectDLL набери в поисковике и поймешь как перехватывать вызовы.
ну а дальше все в твоих руках, скажу сразу как человек решавший эту задачу, задача далеко не тривиальная.

Проще вариант написать свой проксисервер, например на INDY и перенастроить все браузеры на работу через твой прокси.